# Connection timeout from external sources on Docker container via non standard SSL port

Tags: docker, ssl, networking

I did put together a network of containers for a Web App via docker compose. As long as I run it on the standard 443 SSL port (only port exposed to the host) it runs smoothly. When I switch to another port (I need to run multiple container networks on this machine) the connection from outside the server always shows a timeout. Tried port 8443, 9001 and several others. I didn't change anything else on the container itself.

The strange thing is, when I do a `curl` on the server with localhost and the specified port, it shows the App without any problems. So the App is running fine, just the connection from outside is somehow stuck.

The Application itself has a self signed certificate inside the container, but this shouldn't be

What I tried to far (for port 8443):

- `netstat` shows the port 8443 (or any other I tried) open and listended to (same as the 443, where another app is working fine)
- A `curl` on the server with localhost:8443 works fine
- Connection via several server (in different countries): all connection timed out

This is my curl from outside:

```
λ curl -v https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8443/
*   Trying 87.106.152.131...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8443 failed: Timed out
* Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8443: Timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx port 8443: Timed out
```

Not much information there.

My questions are:

- Where can I get some more information about this timeout (and why this is happening)?
- Did anyone else stumbled upon this error and has a solution on hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it work on localhost and on port 443, the only remain explaination for a timeout is a firewall who filter your request.
Also if you try to curl like that you will have issue with certificate, check [this post](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-to-curl-ignore-ssl-certificate-warnings-command-option/) who explain you how to manage self signed certificate or https via IP with curl.

Comment: It was the firewall indeed. I didn't know that some poviders just block every port except 22,80,433. It seems like a security reason, but is quit a bugger when you want to do a little bit more with the app besides showing a simple website.